# Print to an empty file in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

can someone tell me why in python 3.4.2 when I try

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('/home/filename', 'w', 'utf-8') 
print ('something', file = f)
```

it gives me an empty file?

Previously it was working well, but only suddenly it stopped printing to file

Comment: `file=` needs to be a file object. How do you create that file object?

Comment: We cannot tell you why because you need to show us a) how you are opening the file, b) how you are closing or otherwise flushing the buffers of the file and c) how you are checking that the file is empty.

Comment: Why are you using `codecs.open()` when the built-in `open()` function works far better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File writing is buffered to avoid hitting the performance drain that is writing to a disk. Flushing the buffer takes place when you reach a threshold, flush explicitly or close the file.

You have not *closed* the file, did not flush the buffer, and haven't written enough to the file to auto-flush the buffer.

Do one of the following:

- Flush the buffer:

  ```
  f.flush()
  ```

  This can be done with the `flush` argument to `print()` as well:

  ```
  print('something', file=f, flush=True)
  ```

  but the argument requires Python 3.3 or newer.
- Close the file:

  ```
  f.close()
  ```

  or use the file as a context manager (using the `with` stamement):

  ```
  with open('/home/filename', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       print('something', file=f)
  ```

  and the file will be closed automatically when the block is exited (on completion, or an exception).
- Write more data to the file; how much depends on the buffering configuration.